# How to set cipher suites to 2048 bit asymmetric keys

Tags: ssl, cryptography, tls1.2, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to increase the security of the Cipher Suites on Windows 2012 Server.

The [report card](https://globalsign.ssllabs.com/analyze.html?d=test.apgedi.com) on this server shows the following:

Cipher Suites

## TLS 1.2 (suites in server-preferred order)

TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x9f)   DH 1024 bits   FS   WEAK   256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x9e)   DH 1024 bits   FS   WEAK   128

As far as I understand it, it is saying that the bits should be 2048, instead of 1024.  However, I don't understand how to change that.

I have followed [these steps](https://www.howtogeek.com/221080/how-to-update-your-windows-server-cipher-suite-for-better-security/) to improve the Cipher Suites, but it doesn't mention the bits.

For background, these suites are used by the server when sending/receiving EDI documents and I want to ensure no insecure or weak cipher suites are being used.

Comment: The problem part is the `DH 1024 bits`.  You need to increase your DH key size.  How to do that depends on what your server is.  Or you can just disable cipher suites that use a DH key.

Comment: @kelalaka: The comment is unrelated (tls version does not matter for this question) and additionally wrong. The attacks you refer to are mainly about RSA key exchange which is not used in this case. And the parts which are not about RSA key exchange affect TLS 1.3 the same way. And they are an implementation issue, not a protocol issue.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, Thank you.  I found this link which shows how to increase the size on Windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security-updates/securityadvisories/2016/3174644  If you want to post as answer, I will accept.

Comment: @GregGum Showing that Mickeysoft cannot get anything right: if you follow that document then you will only enable 2048 bits and not the higher bit sizes for the Discrete Logarithm Problem that is the base of DH: 0x800 (the value for the regex entry) just is the value 2048. Just entering 2048 would be more logical than the hex value, and you might want to go higher.

Comment: To use stronger key agreement protocols: disable DHE suites and go with ECDHE suites instead. Those are much stronger for smaller key sizes.